# Crossfade images within SVG

Tags: svg

What is the best approach for crossfading two horizontally aligned images in SVG?

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/58xp9/6/) is my approach so far, but I'm having two problems:

1. Within my mask, how can I apply the two gradients coming from oppisite sides? I've only been able to get 1 out of 2 to appear.
2. When the mask is applied to the first image, why is the second image no longer visible? If I am using `objectBoundingBox`, shouldn't the mask just be contained to the element?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to achieve?  There are a number of problems with the approach you're taking.

Comment: Example of one possibility, using a single mask for both elements: http://jsfiddle.net/58xp9/7/.  However, playing around I can see why you're confused: using multiple masks on separate elements is causing serious problems in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/58xp9/8/  The second image disappears completely in Chrome 34; displays as expected in Firefox & Opera -- suggesting this is either a Chrome-specific bug or a new bug in the latest webkit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I gave up on SVG and decided to do it all with JS/Canvas. Thanks, though!

Comment: I can't blame you -- it's a serious bug with Chrome.